# Assigning a variable on the last method statement

Tags: ruby, methods, return-value, assign

Lets say you have a method that assigns a variable to a method call at the end:

```
def this_method(x)
   x = x + 5
   x = some_method_like_multiply_by_two(x)
end
```

and a similar method that doesn't have a variable assignment:

```
def this_method(x)
   x = x + 5
   some_method_like_multiply_by_two(x)
end
```

Which one is better? Is it necessary to have `x =` in the last statement of a method? Is the first one clearer? Does the second one pose a risk to introduce more bugs by whoever read the code because they might not know that its doing something with `x`? Which one is the proper way of coding? When would I want to use the first style (despite the variable is showing as unused in code analysis)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simplify life even further and do:

```
def this_method(x)
   some_method_like_multiply_by_two(x + 5)
end
```

Since `x` is purely local to the method and you are returning the result of calling the other method, updating `x` with intermediate operations accomplishes nothing. Go straight for the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to change the value of "x" as passed into this_method?  If not then "x =" is wasted effort, especially because you are not using x, unless you are returning x from the method.  If you are you have two options:

```
def this_method(x)
   x = x + 5
   x = some_method_like_multiply_by_two(x)
   return x
end
```

or just simply:

```
def this_method(x)
   x = x + 5
   x = some_method_like_multiply_by_two(x)
   x
end
```

Comment: Hi portforwradpodcast, Yes, i am trying to change the value of x. 

    def this_method(x)
       x = x + 5
       some_method_like_multiply_by_two(x)
    end

Why do i need to assign it to x and return it first though ? 
i thought ruby method always return a value and it will return the last statement ?

Comment: Yes, ruby always returns the value of the last statement.  In this case you can probably want `return some_method_like_multiply_by_two(x)` to be explicit to other developers

Comment: Isee, and the "return" statement is not necessary as well right since ruby method always return a value and return the last statement. i.e. if its on the last statement, and its calling other method, we can assume that that method will return something which then gets returned. Talking about the ruby way of minimalistic and implicit magic..

Comment: It would be unusual, as well as unnecessary, to see anything other than just `some_method_like_multiply_by_two(x)` as the last line (I.e., no `return`, no `x =`).